# Laravel 5 - How to add multiple parameters to laravel array for db insert?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I have an array of 3 companies, which need to be inserted into the db but with 2 additional parameters added to them.

```
$companyList = [{"name": "apple", "founder": "steve"},
                {"name": "google", "founder": "larry"},
                {"name": "facebook", "founder": "mark"},
               ];
```

Need to append these 2 parameters for each company (issue is in this step):

```
$companyListFinal = [];
foreach ($companyList as $company) {
  $companyListFinal[] = array_add($company,['keyAppend1' => 'key 1 appended',
                                            'keyAppend2' => 'key 2 appended'];
}
```

The final step is to insert the company list with the appended values into the DB:

```
DB::table('companies')->insert($companyListFinal);
```

I can't seem to be able to append the 2 new parameters to create the final array to insert:`$companyListFinal`

What's the correct way to add the parameters to each company so they are all inserted at bulk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use array_merge instead of array_add

Comment: Thank you, `array_merge` was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using array_push() instead on array_add(). That should do the job.

Comment: I tried array_push() instead but still didn't work. When we print this `$companyListFinal` it should list an array, with 3 objects, each with 4 fields, (the 2 old and the 2 newly appended). I am still unable to print that before entry to db as a check.